# How to switch from input mode into command mode in ed?

Tags: command-line, editors, line-editor, ed

As far as I know, `ed` starts in command mode. Once I input `i`, `a` or `c`, `ed` changes into input mode. So far it worked. Now I read that in order to switch from input mode into command mode one has to input `,` and <kbd>Enter</kbd>. I tried so, but it did not work, I stayed in input mode and had to quit the program with <kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd> without the opportunity to write the text in the buffer onto hard disk.

I am using Linux Mint and the Xfce terminal, how can I switch into command mode?

Answer (score 2):

Enter a single dot on a line of its own.

Comment: thanks very much, i would have never find out that i have to use a point instead of a comma with my bad eyesight.

Answer (score 1):

The ordinary way of ending inserting text when using `i`, `a`, or `c` in `ed` is to write a dot on a line by itself.  This is the documented way of exiting input mode.

The `ed` manual on macOS reads:

> When an input command, such as `a` (append), `i` (insert) or `c` (change), is
> given, `ed` enters input mode.  This is the primary means of adding text to a
> file.  In this mode, no commands are available; instead, the standard input
> is written directly to the editor buffer.  Lines consist of text up to and
> including a newline character.  **Input mode is terminated by entering a single period (`.`) on a line.**

The [POSIX specification for `ed`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ed.html) says

> While `ed` is accepting text, it is said to be in *input mode*.
> In this mode, no commands shall be recognized; all input is merely
> collected. Input mode is terminated by entering a line consisting of
> two characters: a `<period>` (`.`)  followed by a `<newline>`.  This line
> is not considered part of the input text.

You may also use <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> to exit input mode.  If this is done before pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> to commit the current line of text, the current line of text is lost.

Note that <kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd> does not terminate `ed`, but puts it, suspended, in the background of the current shell session.  You may return to the editing session by using `fg` in the shell (or `fg %jobnum` where `jobnum` is the job number of the `ed` job, as reported by the `jobs` built-in utility).